# Add Attendee in Google Calendar Event

Tags: asp.net, google-calendar-api

i am developing my app on google calendar integration. I got the error "Object Not initialized" when i am adding attendee to the EventAttendee object. Please review the code below...

```
 Event Entry = new Event();
    Entry.Summary = MeetingName;
    Entry.Description = MeetingDetails;

    EventDateTime dt_Start = new EventDateTime();
    dt_Start.DateTime = meeting.StartTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.000Z");
    Entry.Start = dt_Start;

    EventDateTime dt_End = new EventDateTime();
    dt_End.DateTime = meeting.EndTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.000Z");
    Entry.End = dt_End;        
    if (invitees != null)
    {
        foreach (Participant invitee in invitees)
        {
            String str = invitee.Email;
            str = invitee.Name;
            Entry.Attendees.Add(new EventAttendee()
            {
                Email = invitee.Email,
                DisplayName = WEB.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(invitee.Name),
                ResponseStatus = "accepted",
                Organizer=false,
                Resource=false
            });
        }
    }
```

place where i am doing "Entry.Attendees.Add(new EventAttendee()" at this point i am getting the error...

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to instantiate the list of EventAttendees first.

Try adding this after you create the entry-

```
Entry.Attendees = new List<EventAttendee>();
```

Then you could try this to add them-

```
var att = new EventAttendee()
                    {
                        DisplayName = "Bill Smith",
                        Email = "emailsmith@smith.test",
                        Organizer = false,
                        Resource = false,
                    };
Entry.Attendees.Add(att);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be setting anything other than the email address for the attendee. The response status is for the attendee to set (why would you be able to accept a meeting for me that you created?) and the Organizer and Resource attributes are set by Google. It may be possible to set a DisplayName but it is not mandatory.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... Even after specifying only email and displayname, i am getting the same problem of Object not initialized. The other attributes for eventatteendee are AdditionalGuest, Comment, Id, Optional, Self. So can you please tell me what are the other things that i need to specify.

Comment: Problem resolved.. I did the same process after creating a separate object of eventatteendeee the it is working fine.